# Ground loop and oscilloscope isolated from earth

Tags: oscilloscope, emc, common-mode

Here is an extract from this [article](https://download.tek.com/document/3AW_19134_2_MR_Letter.pdf)

[image]

It seems that it is missing some words in the extract, causing me some difficulties to understand the beginning it makes the thing harder to me.

Why when the earth ground is not connected to the oscilloscope does the "line-powered instrument" keep the ground loop? It suggests that there is a capacitive coupling between the ground earth and the instrument.  I understand that at very high frequencies even the capacitance in the air can act as a "short circuit" but in this case there is a ground loop every where, it does not really depends on the instrument. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several mechanisms at play, and it does not even depend on specific devices like an oscilloscope, it applies to all devices, such as desktop computers and even humans.

First of all, even if the oscilloscope has mains plug disconnected, the probe ground connects to oscilloscope metal chassis parts. So it is a metal object insulated from other conducting objects - which means it is a capacitor, and so there is capacitance from scope chassis to earth, for example. If you find that weird, please note that also the planet Earth and the Moon can be thought as somewhat conductive objects separated by the insulating void of empty space, so there is also capacitanve betweem them.

So no DC passes through, but AC passes through the capacitor. So adding scope ground clip to any part of the circuit adds capacitance to that part.

Simply disconnecting the scope mains earth wire so it is not grounded makes things worse. The mains inlet typically has an input filter which has capacitors from live and neutral to earth. And since probe ground is connected to the earthed metal chassis, the scope ground simply has capacitors to live and neutral, so scope chassis floats at half mains AC, and connecting scope ground clip anywhere simply means connecting that point via capacitive divisder to half mains voltage AC. The scope metal parts may feel tingly due to capacitive leakage current.

So that's the most dangerous thing to do. Which also means the scope, or any other device like desktop computer with an earthed plug, must not be connected to non-earthed mains socket.

Sometimes the scope is powered via an isolating transformer. This way it has no connection to the earthed neutral wire, and the isolated mains is balanced. There might still be some capacitive coupling between isolating transformer primary and secondary. That may still be dangerous depending on what you are measuring as the scope is not earthed so plugging the ground clip to wrong place may make scope live with mains so touching it will be dangerous.

And still, even the isolation transformer does not remove the fact that the scope has capacitance to earth even if mains plug is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen earth grounded line filters inside any/all 3 pin equipment designs? It is a 2-way filter less than 1mA to ground from line voltages.

This is the loop to your probe ground and with some impedance to line voltages. It can create LC resonances with tracks and wires.

- This means you want ground to be low impedance/reactance, low voltage  and probe to be high impedance/ low capacitance.

Using two probes as a differential amplifier Ch1-Ch2, within limits may be a better solution (using a common earth ground? and/or DC 0V ?

- It depends on DC if it needs to be floating. That supply too has coupling impedance to line with current noise. Floating DC can be sensitive to stray noise and probe noise. So choosing 0V reference = ground, for signal capture, one must consider all the noise and impedances to “other grounds” which serve other purposes, like safety.